# EJB return null Websphere

Tags: jsf-2, ejb-3.0, websphere-8

I'm adjusting my app to work in Websphere 8.5.5 and i found that my app doesn't inject EJB but the same app in Jboss 7.1.1 works ok.

After tha, i create a dummy app and it doesn't work(only add 2 Integers).

Can someone help me?

Edited:

```
package resources;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import co.com.prueba.local.SumadorLocal;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SumadorUI {

    private Integer a;
    private Integer b;
    private Integer c;

    @EJB
    private SumadorLocal sumadorLocal;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){
        System.out.println("Init :"+sumadorLocal);
    }

    public String sumar(){
        c=sumadorLocal.sumador(a, b);
        return null;
    }

    public Integer getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(Integer a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public Integer getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(Integer b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public Integer getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(Integer c) {
        this.c = c;
    }



}
```

UPDATED:

I add new EJB to testing if the problem injection is in ManagedBean or all app, and only the problem is ManagedBean.

Comment: You'll need to post some code and more concrete observations.

Comment: Only based on your tags, I'll assume that you are using JSF. Only provided JSF implementation is [integrated with CDI](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/cweb_cdi_integration.html?lang=en), so if you use custom JSF libraries that might be the reason. Provide code fragment and more description. Try using `@EJB` if you are using `@Inject`

Comment: How are you creating instances of SumadorUI?

Comment: This instance are created by Application Server, this is a managed bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After read and tested, i found a solution. In this link explain how create a implementation of DiscoverableInjectionProvider (Class that help to inject EJB instance) https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/176344/injection-of-stateless-ejbs-‌​into-jsf-managed-beans.html. With this class and adjust web.xml works for me.